# Seeking translation help with か between two verbs and と

Tags: translation, particle-と, particle-か

> よだかは口を大きくひらいて、はねをまっすぐに張って、まるで矢のようにそらをよこぎりました。
> からだがつちにつく**か**つかない**うちに**、よだかはひらり**と**またそらへはねあがりました。

I'm having trouble parsing that 2nd sentence especially the usage of the bolded か , うちに and と.

---

Right now, I'm reading the **か** as "or" (the same way it's used when listing nouns) but I don't know if that's grammatically correct. I'm also reading **うちに** as "while" and **とまた** as "and again", which makes my current reading:

> Yodaka opened his mouth wide, spread his wings straight back and moved through the sky like an arrow. 
> **While** his body was colliding **or** not colliding with the ground, Yodaka **again** nimbly flew up toward the sky.

---

**EDIT:**
I've done some reading on SE, and it seems that:

1. **うちに** does mean "while",
   See: [Difference between うちに and うちから](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42075/difference-between-%E3%81%86%E3%81%A1%E3%81%AB-and-%E3%81%86%E3%81%A1%E3%81%8B%E3%82%892).
2. The **と** is with ひらり as the adverb's particle, See: [<adv> versus <adv>+と versus <adv>+に](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1903/adv-versus-adv%E3%81%A8-versus-adv%E3%81%AB)
3. And (most importantly) both **か** and **うちに** are part of a set grammatical structure as answered below.

Comment: It's not "とまた" but "ひらりと" meaning: Nimbly / Lightly. I think you maybe parsed that bit wrong?

Comment: Ah, I see on Jisho ひらり is described as an "Adverb taking the と particle". That's not something I've seen yet. After reading through SE, I gather that the adverbs that do **NOT** come from adjectives may take と or nothing as a particle. And the と is just for nuance, it draws focus to the adverb but otherwise has no actual meaning. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

VかVないかのうちに (or VかVないうちに) is a set grammatical construction.

It means here the moment where it's not clear whether he hit the ground or not because it happened so fast.

So it's "at the very instant he hit the ground, he bounded back up into the sky"

(see http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n2-grammar-%E3%81%8B%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%AE%E3%81%86%E3%81%A1%E3%81%AB-kanai-no-uchi-ni/ for instance).

Comment: So the か in this case is essentially an "or". Would it be grammatically correct to say that か can be used as an "or" between verbs and not just nouns? (Also, does your structure have a typo? The link shows VかVないか**の**うち or VかVないうち with no 2nd か)

Comment: I believe that the bird was at the moment (うち) of either hitting or not hitting the ground, so 'about to hit the ground' or 'before hitting the ground' would be my suggestion.　ないうちに＝ before (an undesirable thing occurs).