# What is the meaning of うちから

Tags: grammar

This is part of a reading comprehension question in the JLPT 1 exam. [Complete question](https://translationifk.com/ja/luyen-thi-jlpt-n1-ngu-phap-va-doc-hieu-de-so-1-ifk/).

It's actually an excerpt from 「(ほんとうの自分）のつくり方ーー自己物語の心理学」

> 自分の姿がおぼろげにしか見えないうちから、まずは語ることを始めなければならない

What does ないうちから mean? And what does the entire sentence mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between うちに and うちから](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42075/difference-between-%e3%81%86%e3%81%a1%e3%81%ab-and-%e3%81%86%e3%81%a1%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89)

Comment: The ない here is clearly part of 見えない, so the first question is really about うちから (= うち + から). Asking for a translation for the entire sentence is too broad.

Comment: I'd translate it as: "I can only vaguely see the state I'm in, so for starters we have to start talking" or something like that. That なければならない really packs a lot of force behind that "start talking" which is kind of hard to translate to English.

Answer (score 2):

うち in this case means "enclosure". It could be a group of things, a time period, etc.

This is the clause that modifies うち

> 自分の姿がおぼろげにしか見えない

> A shape of yourself (kind of like your true self) is nothing but vaguely visible.

Adding うちから

> 自分の姿がおぼろげにしか見えないうちから 
>  From the enclosure (of time) when your shape is nothing but vaguely visible

The whole sentence:

> 自分の姿がおぼろげにしか見えないうちから、まずは語ることを始めなければならない 
> From the enclosure (of time) when a shape of yourself is nothing but vaguely visible, firstly you must start talking (to yourself).

I think the nuance of うちから is something like "as soon as". We also have まず...

So, idiomatically:

> As soon as you get a glimpse of your true self, you must, before anything else, start talking to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

「○○うちから(内から)」 means "starting from when ○○ is the case".

My guess is that the quoted setence is from literature, and it gives me a very surreal impression. The speaker seems to has a strong belief, something like sense of duty, and/or be determined. So I'm not sure how accurate I can explain, but the speaker seems to be suggesting that he/she must start speaking while s/he can only see themselves vaguely. Anyway a quite unusual situation!

The use of 「うちから」 in the quoted answer [Difference between うちに and うちから](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42075/) is different from yours, but I [gave a detailed explanation](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/100045/) there about 「うちに」and 「うちから」.

BTW you asked about 「ないうちから」, but that ない is paired with the preceding 「しか」, i.e. 「しか...ない」 = there's only.